# Laravel display many specification in one product

Tags: php, laravel-4

i have problem one produk have many `spesifikasi' something like this example

```
Produk 1
  Spek a
  Spek b
  Spek c

Produk 2
  Spek x
  Spek y
```

with this code

**my controller**

```
public function getDashboard() {
    $produk         = Produk::all();
    $spesifikasi    = SpesifikasiProduk::all()->take(2);
    return View::make('admin-page.admin-produk')
                -> with('produk', $produk )
                -> with('spesifikasi', $spesifikasi);
}
```

**my view**

```
@foreach ( $produk as $produk )
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $produk['nama_produk']}}</td>
      <td>{{ substr($produk['deskripsi'], 0, 130).' . . .' }}</td>
      <td>
         @foreach ( $spesifikasi as $spek )
             {{ $spek['title_spek'] }} : {{ $spek['spek'] }} ||
         @endforeach
      </td>
      <td><img src="../{{ $produk['display_thumb'] }}"></td>
```

i get wrong result
it's become something like this

```
Produk 1
  Spek a
  Spek b
  Spek c
  Spek x
  Spek y

Produk 2
  Spek a
  Spek b
  Spek c
  Spek x
  Spek y
```

i get a litle clue where i missing
in foreach spesifikasi (view) i should give some condition
but i don't know how to fix it

my database structure is like this

```
produk { id_produk, nama_produk, deskripsi, dispaly_thumb, created_at, updated_at}

produk_spek { id_spek, id_produk, title_spek, spek, created_at, updated_at }
```

---

**update** Armen Markossyan

this is my model
Produk.php

```
<?php
    class Produk extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'produk';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_produk';
    protected $fillable = array('id_produk', 'nama_produk', 'deskripsi', 'display_thumb');

    public function SpesifikasiProduk() {
        return $this->hasMany( new SpesifikasiProduk, 'id_produk');
    }

    public function ImageProduk() {
        return $this->hasMany(new ImageProduk, 'id_produk');
    }
}
```

SpesifikasiProduk.php

```
<?php
class SpesifikasiProduk extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'produk_spek';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_spek';
    protected $fillable = array('id_produk', 'title_spek', 'spek');

    public function produk() {
       return $this->belongsTo('Produk');
    }
}
```

and i already change to become like this

My Controller

```
public function getDashboard() {
    $produk         = Produk::with('SpesifikasiProduk')->all();
    return View::make('admin-page.admin-produk')
                -> with('produk', $produk );
}
```

My View

```
 @foreach ( $produk as $produk )
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $produk['nama_produk'] }}</td>
         <td>{{ substr($produk['deskripsi'], 0, 130).' . . .' }}</td>
         <td>
             @foreach ( $produk->SpesifikasiProduk as $spek )
                   {{ $spek['title_spek'] }} : {{ $spek['spek'] }} ||
             @endforeach
         </td>
 @endforeach
```

but i still get error like this

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()
```

what i'm missing?

---

**extended *possible create new thread**

```
public function SpesifikasiProduk() {
    return $this->hasMany( new SpesifikasiProduk, 'id_produk')->take(2);
}
```

let say produk A has 4 spesification
produk B has 3 spesification
produk Chas 5 spesification

with above code, it's give result something like this

```
Produk A
   - spek 1
   - spek 2
Produk B
produk C
```

if i change `take` value to 6
the result is

```
Produk A
   - spek 1
   - spek 2
   - spek 3
   - spek 4       
Produk B
   - spek 1
   - spek 2
produk C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read about relationships:
http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Read your own words: "one produk have many spesifikasi". This means that you can establish a "hasMany" relationship between `Produk` and `SpesifikasiProduk`.

Do it like follows:

```
// Produk model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Produk extends \Eloquent {

    public function spesifikasi()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(new SpesifikasiProduk, 'id_produk');
    }

}
```

Your controller code:

```
public function getDashboard() {
    $produk = Produk::with('spesifikasi')->get();
    return View::make('admin-page.admin-produk')
                -> with('produk', $produk);
}
```

Your view:

```
@foreach ( $produk as $produk )
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $produk['nama_produk']}}</td>
      <td>{{ substr($produk['deskripsi'], 0, 130).' . . .' }}</td>
      <td>
         @foreach ( $product->spesifikasi as $spek )
             {{ $spek['title_spek'] }} : {{ $spek['spek'] }} ||
         @endforeach
      </td>
      <td><img src="../{{ $produk['display_thumb'] }}"></td>
@foreach
```

Good luck!

**UPD:**

There are many ways to perform what you want.

The easiest way is to use `@for` instead of `@foreach`:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
    {{ $product->spesifikasi[$i]['title_spek'] }} : {{ $product->spesifikasi[$i]['spek'] }} ||
@endfor
```

Of course, you have to remove `take(2)` from the model.

Comment: i change ->all() to ->get() and everything running smooth thanks

Comment: hm...i get confused how to limit take only 2 "spesifikasi"....
if i used  $produk = Produk::with('SpesifikasiProduk')->get()-take(2);
it's just take 2 produk only..not spesifikasi

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's 'get', not 'all'. Try adding `->take(2)` after `hasMany(new SpesifikasiProduk, 'id_produk')`.